# Is iPad II camera acceptable for proctored exam?

Tags: certification

I have an iPad II and was wondering if the camera in that is acceptable for the proctored exam camera requirement.

Comment: It is acceptable if proctor doesn't know about that. :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kryteriononline.com/online_exams/, especially the FAQ section at the bottom?

You'd need a way to link your iPad to your laptop / desktop, make it recognized as a camera (as a working video capturing device rather than say "external disk" from which you can sync images or music). And it would have to be accessible by browser's Flash plugin.

Sounds like a pretty tricky setup and to be fair they quite explicitly mention "webcam" or "one monitor" as the exam's requirements...

You can try your setup at http://www.kryteriononline.com/support/ but I'd consider simply asking them (https://www.kryteriononline.com/contact_us/) - don't trust people that write random stuff on the internet if it's a matter of $200+ and possibly being banned... Or just consider the travel to testing centre, it's one-time thing and later you'll be able to take the maintenance exams at home.